# Cauchy-Schwarz argument to prove this inner product is zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the space of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}$ which are nonzero only at finitely many $x$. Let $h$ be a positive semi-definite function. For $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$, define:
$$\langle f,g\rangle_{h} = \sum_{x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{d}}\overline{f(x)}g(y)h(x-y)$$
which is well-defined and nonnegative since $h$ is positive semi-definite. I want to prove that the set $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ formed by those $f \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\langle f,f\rangle_{h} = 0$ is a vector subspace of $\mathcal{F}$. To do it, I need to show that:
$$\text{Re}\langle f,g\rangle_{h} = 0.$$
My question is: how do I prove it? I know that it follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for semi-norms, but I would like to have an explicit calculation. I couldn't find one, however.

PS: By positive semi-definite I mean that $h$ is continuous, satisfies $h(0) = 1$ and $|h(x)| \le 1$ and:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}z_{i}\bar{z}_{j}h(x_{i}-x_{j}) \ge 0$$
for every $z_{1},...,z_{N} \in \mathbb{C}$, $x_{1},...,x_{N}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: you mean $h$ in the PS

Comment: Yes! Fixed already, many thanks

Comment: Use polarization identity: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/06/18/inner-product-from-norm/

Comment: @geetha290krm OP used polarization to find $f+g\in \cal F_0\iff {\rm Re}\langle f,g\rangle_h=0$, but $f+g\in\cal F_0$ is what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Suggestion: you want to show that if $f,g \in \cal F_0$ then so is $af + bg$. First examine the cases where $f$ and $g$ are both only non-zero for a single point: one case is the point is the same for both. The other case is when it is a different point. Note that these cases cover a Hamil basis for $\cal F_0$.